# style not being applied to object

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following function in my JavaScript file:

```
 function menu_display(a) {
  document.getElementsById("dropmenu2").style.visibility="visible";
   }
```

The problem is the style is not being applied on my object (the function is getting called, I checked that using an alert). In fact, the only suggestions by Microsoft visual web developer for this object are: constructor, toString, valueOf, isProtypeOf and a few more. It is not even suggesting that 'style' can be applied. What is the problem?

After fixing `getElementsById` by replacing with `getElementById`, the function works fine when I place it in my html file, but if I place it in an external JavaScript file, then the function is getting called (I checked that), but yet again style is not one of the suggestions. This time there are no spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsById()` is not a function of document (or of anything). You're looking for `getElementById()`.

```
document.getElementById("dropmenu2").style.visibility = "visible";
```

[Check it out on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)

Comment: What about Elements? It should be Element - `getElementById`

Comment: oh yes....'s' it is....ms web developer just f****d me...i used its getElementsById() suggestion. Thanx :):)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getElementsById()` is not a valid JS function.  The proper function is `getElementById()`, singular, not plural, because the HTML spec only allows a single element on a page to have a particular ID. Element IDs *must* be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You have two typos:

`Elements` should be Element in [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
`syle` should be [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style).

```
 document.getElementById("dropmenu2").style.visibility = "visible";
```